# Is there a way to override markup in WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, twig, wordpress-theming

I have been working with the [Woo Commerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) plug-in which allows to override [its templates](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/templates) by placing a new version of them in a `/woocommerce` folder at the directory of a theme.

However, I can't seem to do the same when I need to override markup for th particular [Woo Commerce Gateway Paypal Express Checkout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/) plug-in. Am I missing something? I noticed that markup is directly built in classes which is slightly different to how Woo Commerce arranges it with templates.

The markup I want to override allows for the order confirmation and payment confirmation pages to be customized. These seem to render with `page.php`. But the markup is present across various files in the plug-in.

I am considering creating a copy of the plug-in and add my own overrides but as I understand this comes at a cost of future updates.

For context no layout plugins like Div or Elementor are being used, this is a theme written from scratch that makes use of `.twig` templates.

Any thoughts or information on how to go about this would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I believe it is better to direct your question to the [plugin's support team](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/) or [this one](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/express-checkout-paypal-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/). Many plugins have similar names, always provide a link in your question to the relevant plugin. Regards

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r, I have added the link to the plug-in now. I have [opened an issue in their repo](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/issues/825) but it seemed that was more directed at bugs so though of asking here. I'll get in touch with the support team.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to customize neither that precise plugin source code, but are you sure that you don't have any hooks/ function to override to change that particular template? Usually woocommerce stuff is made like that

Comment: I suppose one of the issues is that some of these require the current object. For instance `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing', array( $this, 'paypal_billing_details' ) );` cannot be run without the current instance and I am not sure how to find it and pass the correct one when adding my own action.